# Avoid appending cookies to every request to the server

Tags: asp.net, performance, cookies

I used firebug to check the performance of my website. During the verification of one page I got some weird scenarios.

I have one page which contains 7 jQuery files and 2 css files and some images. 
When any request is sent to the server from the browser it sends cookies related to that domain, but as it contains static jQuery, css and image files, the browser also sends requests for these files to the server.

And here is the problem with every request for a static file it sends cookies of nearly 1 to 2 kb.

I want to avoid these cookies being sent to server when the browser requests a static file only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Serve those files from a cookieless subdomain, or CDN.

This should help you: [Serving Static Content from a Cookieless Domain](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/)

Answer (score 3):

Browsers send cookies for every appropriate request on the domain they were set from; there is no differentiation between static or dynamic. In fact, there is no way at all for the browser to know which is which.

There is a solution, though; use a different domain for static content, such as images and scripts. It could be a subdomain of your main site, even.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are for the purpose of roundtripping data between requests. It is their intended behaviour to be sent for all requests. If you are having issues because your cookies are too large, try to fix your cookies, not the protocol.